# IE supports forEach(...) when invoked fromthe console but not when called from the code

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, internet-explorer-11

I'm running this snippet the console. In IE it produces the output just as expected. Running the same in Cr and FF for reference confirms the congruence of behavior.

```
["a", "b"].forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

However, when running the following script, I'm getting errors telling me that the object hasn't *forEach(...)* declared on it. The issue occurs in IE but not in Cr nor FF.

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll("ul.application>li>a");
menus.forEach(function(element) { ... }
```

I've checked that the variable *menus* is declared and that picking it's elements produces what I would expect, i.e. *menus[0]* exists and is a tag. It looks a bit differently in IE compared to the others but it might be just the different rendition.

I've been blessed working with Cr and FF so my experience in dealing with IE is limited. Googling didn't give me much wisdom, neither.

How do I troubleshoot it further?

Comment: Simply because NodeList isn't an Array (and IE/Safari dont support NodeList.forEach, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)).

Comment: As far as I know, `querySelectorAll` returns a `HtmlCollection` which is not the same as an `Array` Chrome might have an internal polyfill for it, hence t works there.

Comment: That "blessing" is also a curse :) When browsers compensate by implementing their own internal workarounds like that, they make IE look broken and also make you rely on custom implementations that may or may not change in future version :) For example, there is no guarantee that Chrome will continue supporting to extend the HtmlCollection with a forEach, they have done it in the past :) While IE is terrible in a lot of ways, if you have to support multiple browser, including specific versions of IE, maybe getting things to work in IE first is better for those reasons?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl that's actually a good suggestion. I just prefer Cr and FF because I feel that the tools are better. But I will have to check stuff in IE more carefully. (Well, my dedicated tester will have to, hehe.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically `document.querySelectorAll` would return a `nodeList` an array like object not an array. You have to convert it to an array before invoking array functions over that.

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll("ul.application>li>a");
menus = [].slice.call(menus);
menus.forEach(function(element) { ... });
```

If your environment supports ES6 then you can use `Array.from()`

```
var menus = document.querySelectorAll("ul.application>li>a");
menus = Array.from(menus);
menus.forEach(function(element) { ... });
```

Comment: How would *[Array.from(menus)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)* relate to *[Array.apply(null,menus)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)*? I understand the concepts as described in the docs but I see two different suggestions here by two well-reputed users and I wonder why the different suggestions. Is one of them about to be obsolete? More commonly used?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Both are good to use. `Array.from` is a dedicated function introduced in ES6 to avoid difficulties in converting iterable objects to an array. Some example for iterable objects would be `string`, `arguments` etc.. On the other hand, `Array.apply(` is just a way to convert it, if your environment doesn't support ES6. There are plenty of ways to convert it in ES5. To bring all the methods to a single junction point, they introduces `Array.from`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem of the browser, it is more like you get an array like object, with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll). It returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is iterable, but not directly with array methods.

But you can borrow the method from `Array.prototype`, like this one

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(menu, function(element) { /* ... */ });
```

If you like to get first a real array, you could convert it with

```
array = Array.apply(null, menu);
```

Comment: You are **so right**! That's precisely what it said in IE's console. I thought it was just a goofy way to tell me the same thing. My ignorance being the issue. Now, why does it work in FF and Cr? Do they have a built-in magic for that translation?

Comment: they have extended the language.

Comment: How would *[Array.from(menus)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)* relate to *[Array.apply(null,menus)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)*? I understand the concepts as described in the docs but I see two different suggestions here by two well-reputed users and I wonder why the different suggestions. Is one of them about to be obsolete? More commonly used?

Comment: `Array.from` is new with ES6, and does not work with IE, according to the [compatibillity list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility). that means, `Array.from` is not an option for you.

Answer (score 4):

Little late, but it might be useful if someone has the same problem and doesn't want/can't replace all forEach methods with `[].forEach.call(elements, fn(el))`. Here is polyfill that works for ie11

```
if (! Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(NodeList.prototype, 'forEach')) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'forEach', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, 'forEach'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to add one line at the beginning:

```
window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach && (NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach) // make IE support forEach
```

And after that, you can use forEach in IE like in other normal browsers.